# Why aren't Stack Snippets available in the documentation beta?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-snippets, documentation

Standard code highlighting works as it has for ages in the Documentation beta, but the Stack Snippets function doesn't exist there. Why not? For HTML, JavaScript (and the millions of related JS libraries), and CSS this seems like it would be highly useful.

Comment: Agree. For documenting many front-end frameworks, like e.g. Bootstrap, having all three (html, js, css) available for examples would be very helpful.

Comment: Even just for HTML or JavaScript in isolation, snippets are great (now that there's an in-snippet console).

Comment: And not only for HTML, JS and CSS are snippets good also for Python, .NET and many other programming languages.

Comment: It would be nice if there was the ability to specify a Stack Snippet “template” in the tag, so for example, you could make a Python snippet with skulpt/pypy.js.

Answer (score 11):

We may revisit this later as Documentation matures as a feature, but initially... The goal is to document Javascript (or HTML or CSS) as is. I feel like any example that uses all three might be overkill... But I don't feel super strongly about. Having at least the option of runnable examples would be pretty dope.

If you want, feel free to retag this as [feature-request] to make sure it's on our radar going forward.

Comment: *"any example that uses all three might be overkill"* - It's not like all three is mandatory for a snippet... For example HTML doc can have runnable snippets having only HTML, JavaScript doc can have only that without any *custom* HTML or CSS...

Comment: @TJ I agree with that in principle, but I also feel that snippets as a feature tends to encourage the use of all three to produce complete-ish answers to specific questions. Which may well be what we also want to do in Docs. Or it may end up being too confusing. One way to find out, but right at launch is probably not that time. We're doing plenty of other confusing things. ;)

Comment: For me an actual working sample in docs where possible is **GOLD**

Comment: @AdamLear Isn't documentation about **examples**, what's the point in examples you cannot run? It just makes it annoying for the reader of the documentation to copy the code in a fiddle and run them.

Comment: Note that we already have links to jsFiddle up on the JavaScript docs (some of them <sarcastic>helpfully</sarcastic> marked up with `<kbd>`)...

Comment: I'm trying to help get the `web-audio` documentation off the ground and having working snippets in order to hear example sounds would be very helpful

Comment: Agree with @Gman plz add this feature!

Comment: i'm trying to improve the SVG documentation. Having visible feedback is of most importance there.